# Recording webcam video with parameter control in chunks

Tags: c#, computer-vision, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to record video from a webcam for a long period of time - about 16 hours - and I really don't want the application to crash.

I would like to break the video up into chunks while recording, probably about 10GB each or so. I have seen software for other camera types that does this, but not for webcams.

Further, I need to be able to control camera parameters such as white-balance and exposure.

I have tried Accord.NET, but I'm getting intermittent memory corruption problems. I have tried OpenCV, but it doesn't support webcam properties well on Windows and I can't control the bitrate of the files I'm recording.

Are there any other frameworks that will do this easily? I can't be first person to face this problem.

Are there any example projects of this for DirectShow or MediaFoundation? I'm familiar with DirectShow, but not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture).

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try it today and accept your answer if it works.